# Деплой в Google App Engine через пайплайн GitLab CI и сервис-аккаунт [Solved]

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, gitlab-ci

Есть приложение на Java, собирается пайплайном в GitLab CI, затем деплоится в GAE. Для деплоя используется сервис-аккаунт с ролью Google App Engine admin. Google App Engine Administration API включен.

При запуске в gitlab-runner команды `mvn appengine:deploy` появляется следующее:

`The following URL can be used to authenticate:
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
Attempting to open it in your browser now.
Unable to open browser. Please open the URL above and copy the resulting code.`

Что нужно сделать, чтобы обойти предложение авторизовать приложение через браузер?

Заранее спасибо за любой совет или линк на документацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя [App Engine SDK-based App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven), вы должны авторизовать приложение в своем аккаунте, что и происходит через открытие сслыки в браузере. Но с использованием [Cloud SDK-based Apache Maven and the App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-maven) maven начинает использовать существующий `gcloud` конфиг, и service account работает как надо.

Прямым текстом это нигде не упоминается, так что не сведущему в вопросе человеку может быть не очевидно.

Service account при этом должен иметь в целевом проекте следующие роли:

- App Engine Admin
- Storage Admin

Итого, ваш `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml` должен содержать следующие строки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

    <application>app_name</application>
    <service>gae_service_name</service>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <instance-class>F1</instance-class>

    <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>

</appengine-web-app>
```

pom.xml должен содержать следующий плагин:

```
    <plugin>
       <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
       <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.1</version>
    </plugin>
```

а не этот:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.58</version>
</plugin>
```

и команда deploy будет выглядеть следующим образом:

`mvn appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.version=1-2-3`

или через `gcloud`:

`gcloud app deploy --version 1-2-3`